# Photo-voltaic power source connecting to a grid: can I feed the greed?

Tags: power-engineering

Let's say I have a PV power source generating 50/60 Hz 230VAC power. I could connect this power directly to the grid assuming that I will consume all generated power for my own needs or, if the power generation exceeds my needs (and if the battery is fully charged), I can 'sell' the energy to the grid.

However I prospect that I will not be able to sell the power to the grid at least not in any case. For example in my country (Russia) I would need to get very expensive certificate (as I know Alstom got this one for about $50 000 several years ago) to be able to connect to grid as a power source. I don't know what is the situation in other countries (probably with more distributed power generation strategy). Most of my interest is Germany experience.

However I could connect the `house` to PV power source and use grid only if I don't have enough power from PV elements or from the battery. If I generate MORE power than I (and battery) need - I will through it to the heat.

Moreover: I heard about "[Power islanding effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islanding)". Let's say part of grid was turned off for maintenance but my PV system will still feed the grid and make it dangerous to maintenance.

Could anyone comment my thoughts on the topic?

Comment: This is more a "ask a specific question, show the work/research, get an answer site" rather than a comments site. However The certificate/ legal regulation of equipment you speak of applies to all countries i believe. From a safety point of view "Power Islanding effect" is a real danger. The equipment must disconnect when the grid turns off or you risk killing the people working on the grid. Fire fighters also have the problem as well. You can't turn off a solar panel, just disconnect it at some point.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly common in the UK for houses to have PV panels on the roof and, in some cases, for householders to sell electricity back to their supplier

See http://www.bettergeneration.co.uk/green-energy-factsheets/feed-in-tariffs.html

> A Feed-in Law states that electricity suppliers are obliged to pay a fixed price for electricity generated from renewable sources, set above the market price for fossil fuels, with the idea being that this will stimulate a much wider take-up of microgeneration. The FIT is made up of:
>
> - Generation Tariff - Utilities are **obliged** to purchase all renewable electricity produced by households or businesses, with the price per kWh depending on the technology and the size of the capacity;
> - Export Tariff - Any generated electricity that is not used by the premises can be exported to the grid, with the tariff set at 3p/kWh;
> - Avoided Costs - Not only will households be paid for all renewable energy generated, they will also save the costs that they previously would have paid in electricity bills.
>
> As is clear from the above, one of the great things about the FiT is the financial reward. You would be paid for all Renewable Energy produced, even if 100% of the electricity is used on your premises.

[image]

```
Summary of solar PV tariffs

Total installed    Generation tariff with            Lower tariff 
capacity (kW)      eligibility date or after         (if EPC requirement not met)
                   1 January 2014 and before         with eligibility date on or
                   1 April 2014                      after 1 January 2014
                                                 and before 1 April 2014

<4kW (new build 
and retrofit)      14.90p/kWh                        6.61p/kWh

>4-10kW            13.50p/kWh                        6.61p/kWh

>10-50kW           12.57p/kWh                        6.61p/kWh

stand-alone        6.61p/kWh                         6.61p/kWh
```

<sup>From an [energy-saving trust](http://www.energysavingtrust.org.uk/Generating-energy/Getting-money-back/Feed-In-Tariffs-scheme-FITs)</sup>

> If you generate your own electricity (eg with solar panels or a wind turbine) your energy supplier might pay you money. This is called a ‘Feed-in Tariff’ (FIT).
>
> How the scheme works
>
> You’ll get a set amount for each unit (kilowatt hour or kWh) of electricity you generate. The rates vary depending on:
>
> - the size of your system
> - what technology you install
> - when your technology was installed
> - who put the technology in place - you need to use a certified installer
>
> Contact installer companies or an electricity supplier for more information. You can receive payments from your current energy supplier, or you can choose a different one from the list of registered suppliers.
>
> The export tariff - selling surplus energy
>   As well as the generation tariff, you can also sell any extra units you don’t use back to your electricity supplier. This is called an ‘export tariff’.
>
> You’ll get 4.5p per unit of electricity:
>
> - for solar panels where you applied for FIT on or after 1 August 2012
> - for other technologies where you applied for FIT on or after 1 December 2012
>     If you applied for FIT before these dates you’ll continue to get 3.2p for each unit of electricity.

<sup>From [UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/feed-in-tariffs)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Could you make clear: the price is just 3 penny per kWh?

Comment: @Roman: See updates, it's complicated. You get paid to generate your own electricity that you use yourself. You also get paid for any surplus electricity that you feed back into the grid. The amounts vary. The tariffs change from time to time (but are generally fixed for long periods to encourage householders to make investments with a long-term payback)

Comment: Worth pointing out that (UK) this tariff ONLY applies for standards-compliant PV installations by certified installers using expensive components certified to appropriate standards. Given the grid connection, this is justified! A home-built PV installation could be lower cost but without regulatory approval you keep it off-grid : (there may be an exception below 600W when the grid-tie inverter is a certified component)